# Your opinions about an idea for better php applications security?

Tags: php, security, applications

As we all know, security is very important when making any kind of application. That's why I came up with this idea, or rather I already made it happen. Thing is I am not sure whether it is really securing my applications, or is it just extra weight.

To keep it simple: I made a simple function that enables "admins/owners" to change the names of folders within an app. Each folder is given an ID (through some file/controller that exists in the folder itself). That's the gist of it.

As I already mentioned, it is a working "countermeasure". I'm sure there are better alternatives, like HTACCESS. But, I don't have the guts to learn other methods (Sorry for that xD).

So, once again... What do you think of this idea? Is it fine to use it? or is it bad?

I know that I should consider running/execution time optimization, and it would be much appreciated if you could share some tips & tricks or tutorials.

Comment: How does this make the application more secure?

Comment: That's exactly the point of this thread actually! xD
Suppose you have to access some important files (eg. Includes)... if the name of that folder is 'includes' and it remains the same all the time, it might be more vulnerable and easier to "hack", whereas changing its name regularly would somehow prevent the hacking... That's my thought.

Comment: `if the name of that folder is 'includes' and it remains the same all the time, it might be more vulnerable and easier to "hack"` what make you think that an invariable folder name is more vulnerable than a dynamic one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point and click way to give very lame sysadmins a form of security trough obscurity. It's gonna be more of an hassle for mantaining and updating than a way to defy attacks. Might help against bots written by 15 yr. old script kiddies, but that's it.

Comment: I thought about cron jobs for that matter. But I do agree that it's so much of a hassle which is why I'm consulting the more experienced programmers!